# How to create a directory with specman

Tags: specman

I need to write several files for debugging, i'm interested in putting them is a directory.
How can i check if the directory exists? and if not to create it?
I tried to set the file name with the directory, but since it doesn't exist it failed

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a directory exists using the `file_is_dir(...)` function. If it doesn't, you can use the `system(...)` function to create it:

```
if not files.file_is_dir("some_dir") {
  compute system("mkdir some_dir");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
system("any system command here as a string");
```

and as a command use `mkdir -p new_directory`.

The '-p' option allows you to create the full path automatically (if parent directories don't exist then they will be automatically created) and if the `new_directory` already exists, `mkdir` will return without an error.

According to [this](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_mkdir.htm)

> **mkdir [OPTION] DIRECTORY...**
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.
>
> Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options
>   too.
>
> -m, --mode=MODE - set permission mode (as in chmod), not rwxrwxrwx - umask
>
> **-p, --parents - no error if existing, make parent directories as needed**